# swagger not detected when i remove @configuration

Tags: maven, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

i try to integrate swagger into my  spring boot project but i receive always an error : 
"Error creating bean with name 'modelMapperImpl': Failed to introspect bean class [springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.ModelMapperImpl] " but when i remove @configuration from swaggerConfig swagger will not be detected ,here is my code :

WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", 
"PATCH");
}
}
```

SwaggerConfig

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration

public class SwaggerConfig {
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
}
```

Pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is there more to the crash log like a caused by?  Seems like similar crashes on the web have more caused by sections after Failed to introspect bean class.  Which is probably a dependency problem.  Either a missing one or an incompatible one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mycompany.cors")
public class CorsSettings {

final private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsSettings.class);
private List<String> origins = new ArrayList<>();

public CorsSettings() {
    log.debug("construct CorsSettings");
}

public List<String> getOrigins() {
    return this.origins;
}

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    if (origins != null) {
        log.debug("corsOrgins=" + origins);
    } else {
        log.error("corsOrgins=null");
    }
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(origins.toArray(new String[origins.size()]));
        }
    };
}
}
```

Next in Config

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("My Swagger API").description("This is a my swagger server")
            .license("").licenseUrl("https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT").termsOfServiceUrl("").version("1.0.0")
            .contact(new Contact("My name", "://www.mycompany.com", "myemail@mycompany.com"))
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Docket customImplementation() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.mycompany.path")).build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}

}
```

Then in application.yml

```
mycompany:
  cors:
    origins:
      - ${origin1:http://localhost:8080}
      - ${origin2:http://localhost:8080}
      - ${origin3:http://localhost:8080}
      - ${origin4:http://localhost:8080}
```

Comment: Make sure to populate the com.mycompany.path in basePackage with the correct class path root.

Comment: same result Error creating bean with name 'modelMapperImpl': Failed to introspect bean class [springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.ModelMapperImpl]